# Prime no.s function not working in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, type-declaration

I am new to Haskell, but I know C. I'm referring *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* as study source and currently learning about "List comprehension".
Since I can easily make a prime numbers program in C, I tried the same in Haskell with the following code:

```
primes = [x | x <- [2..100], null [f | f <- [2..round (x/2)], 0 == rem x f]]
--it creates a list of prime numbers upto 100. `f` denotes factors.
--working principle: this code adds those numbers to the main list who have no factors (excluding 1 and the number itself.
```

But it is showing a big error in my GHCi:

```
train.hs:84:20:
    No instance for (Enum t0)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘2 .. 100’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include primes :: [t0] (bound at train.hs:84:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Enum (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Enum Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
      ...plus 8 others
    In the expression: [2 .. 100]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [2 .. 100]
    In the expression:
      [x |
         x <- [2 .. 100],
         null [f | f <- [2 .. round (x / 2)], 0 == rem x f]]

train.hs:84:21:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal ‘2’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include primes :: [t0] (bound at train.hs:84:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: 2
    In the expression: [2 .. 100]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [2 .. 100]

train.hs:84:49:
    No instance for (Integral t0) arising from a use of ‘round’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: t0 (bound at train.hs:84:15)
      primes :: [t0] (bound at train.hs:84:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the expression: round (x / 2)
    In the expression: [2 .. round (x / 2)]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: f <- [2 .. round (x / 2)]

train.hs:84:57:
    No instance for (Fractional t0) arising from a use of ‘/’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: t0 (bound at train.hs:84:15)
      primes :: [t0] (bound at train.hs:84:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    In the first argument of ‘round’, namely ‘(x / 2)’
    In the expression: round (x / 2)
    In the expression: [2 .. round (x / 2)]

train.hs:84:65:
    No instance for (Eq t0) arising from a use of ‘==’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: t0 (bound at train.hs:84:40)
      x :: t0 (bound at train.hs:84:15)
      primes :: [t0] (bound at train.hs:84:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Eq (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Eq e) => Eq (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
      ...plus 28 others
    In the expression: 0 == rem x f
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: 0 == rem x f
    In the first argument of ‘null’, namely
      ‘[f | f <- [2 .. round (x / 2)], 0 == rem x f]’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm sorry, but I rechecked my code, but it just seems fine, considering the syntax.

However, when I put the same code in my `ghci>`, the result is bit different:

```
Prelude> let primes = [x | x <- [2..100], null [f | f <- [2..round (x/2)], 0 == rem x f]]
Prelude> primes

<interactive>:12:1:
    No instance for (Integral t0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I would be glad if I get to know my mistake.

Same code from my textbook:----------------

1. I had to declare `primes` as integer list like this:

```
primes :: [Integer]
```

But why did this problem did not occur for other functions?
Like this function just worked fine. I had not declare `listCom`'s type:

```
listCom = [2*x | x <- [1..50], rem x 3 == 0]
```

2. I have to modify the draw list of factors by adding `fromIntegral` with `x/2`:

```
f <- [2..round (fromIntegral x/2)]
```

Now why I have to state that even if I have already converted `x/2` to integer using `round`?

Edit:
If there is problem with `[2..round (x/2)]`, then does this code work perfectly fine:

```
ii = 33
samLis = [2..round (ii/2)]
```

Comment: Roughly put, division `/` is for floating point numbers. Since you're working with integers, use instead ``x `div` 2`` which is integer division (already rounded down).

Comment: Please be aware that posting *any* AI-generated content is [a violation of the policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Posting a summary of what you learnt from AI should be OK, I guess. No part of this post (AFAICS) is AI-generated.

Comment: @chi The policy says "all use of generative AI", so maybe it is not OK. I'm not here to enforce it or judge anybody anyway. Just a word of caution.

Comment: thank you, @chi. I change it to something else. (is it legal?!)

Comment: Prime numbers are actually a nice path into the study of Haskell. Just look at our [relevant Wiki chapter](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) for various, much more efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now why I have to state that even if I have already converted x/2 to integer using round?

It is not converting `x/2`, it is converting `x`. Indeed, [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) works with *fractional* numbers, and an `Integer` or any other integral number is not a `Fractional` number, so without the `fromIntegral`, it requires that `x` is both `Fractional` (because you use it in `x/2`), and `Integral` (since you use it in [**`rem :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:rem)), while one can technically "fabricate" such type, it makes no sense: a number type is either integral, or fractional, not both.

If you thus implement this as:

```
primes = [x | x <- [2 .. 100], null [f | f <- [2 .. round (fromIntegral x / 2)], 0 == rem x f]]
```

we're done.

The prime check is however far from efficient: we can for example already stop at √n for checking.

> But why did this problem did not occur for other functions? Like this function just worked fine. I had not declare `listCom`'s type.

Because there it uses type defaulting rules, will use `Integer`, and since you don't use `x` in any function that forces a type constraint it can not satisfy, there is no problem.

Comment: If there is problem with `[2..round (x/2)]`, then how does this code work fine:
`ii = 33  <nextline> samLis = [2..round (ii/2)]`

Comment: @Suraj: it postpones assigning types when needed, so `ii` has type `Num a => a`, it can thus eventually be a `Double` which is `Fractional`.

Comment: @Suraj There is no problem with `[2..round (x/2)]` *alone*; the problem is the use of *both* `/` and `rem`. So, for example, ```ii = 33 `rem` 34; samLis = [2..round (ii/2)]``` has the same problem as in your original question, even though ```ii = 33 `rem` 34; samLis = [2..ii]``` is fine and ```ii = 33; samLis = [2..round (ii/2)]``` is fine.